# Mechanism of retro aldol condensation of hydroxycyclopropylketone

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The reactants were treated with $\ce{NaOH} $. How the product here obtained. Can you show me the reaction mechanism for this. I found this is somewhat  Retro Aldol Condensation. But how?[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You deprotonate the alcohol, and then flip bonds to create the enolate. There are two enolates possible, so swapping bonds gives you the terminal one, which can attack the aldehyde to form the 5-ring. Elimination of water gives you the product.

[image]